# Dockerfile をbuildしたいのですが以下のエラーが出て出来ません

Tags: docker, postgresql

Dockerfile をbuildしたいのですが以下のエラーが出て出来ません。

postgresのダウンロードが開けないエラーのようです。
何か別の形にして、Dockerfileをbuildする方法はないでしょうか？

```
Cannot open: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm. Skipping.

Error: Nothing to do

The command '/bin/sh -c rm -f /etc/rpm/macros.image-language-conf &&     
sed -i '/^override_install_langs=/d' /etc/yum.conf &&     
yum -y update &&     
yum -y reinstall glibc-common &&     ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime &&     
echo $'ZONE="Asia/Tokyo"\nUTC=false' > /etc/sysconfig/clock &&     
yum clean all &&     
yum -y install openssh-server &&     
yum -y install openssh-clients &&     
yum -y install vsftpd &&     
yum clean all &&     
yum install -y epel-release &&     
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm &&     
yum clean all &&     yum install -y --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php php-cli php-devel php-common php-mbstring php-fpm php-gd php-mcrypt php-opcache php-pdo php-xml php-pgsql php-zip php-process &&     yum clean all &&     echo $'[nginx]\nname=nginx repo\nbaseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/\ngpgcheck=0\nenabled=1' > /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo &&     yum -y install nginx &&     yum clean all &&     sed -i -e "/^gpgkey=/a exclude=postgresql*" /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo &&     yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm &&     yum -y install --enablerepo=pgdg96,postgresql postgresql-server &&     yum clean all &&     echo 'root:root' | chpasswd &&     yum -y install git &&     yum -y install sudo &&     sed -i -e "s/#.*%wheel.*ALL=(ALL).*NOPASSWD:.*ALL/# %wheel\tALL=(ALL)\t\tNOPASSWD: ALL\nadmin\tALL=(ALL)\t\tNOPASSWD:\tALL\nnginx\tALL=(ALL)\t\tNOPASSWD:\tALL/g"  /etc/sudoers &&     yum -y install zip &&     yum -y install unzip &&     sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data --encoding=utf8 --no-locale &&     yum clean all &&     /usr/sbin/useradd admin &&     echo 'admin:root' | chpasswd &&     /usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/iws &&     /usr/bin/chown admin:admin /var/iws &&     systemctl enable postgresql-9.6.service &&     systemctl enable php-fpm.service &&     systemctl enable vsftpd &&     systemctl enable nginx.service' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: `Dockerfile` の内容も質問文に含めてみてください。

Comment: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/ を確認しましたか？
おそらく、pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-11.noarch.rpm に変わっているようです。